# Chronicle Map v3.9.0 returning different sizes

Tags: chronicle-map

I am using v3.9.0 of Chronicle Map where I have two processes where Process A writes to a ChronicleMap and Process B just initializes with the same persistent file that A uses. After loading, I print Map.size in Process A and Process B but I get different Map size. I am expecting both sizes to be the same. In what cases, can I see this behaviour?

How can I troubleshoot this problem? Is there any kind of flush operation required?

One thing, I tried to do is to dump the file using getAll method but it dumps everything as a json on a single file which is pretty much killing any of the editors I have. I tried to use MapEntryOperations in Process B to see if anything interesting happening but seems like it is mainly invoked when something is written into the map but not when Map is initialized directly from the persistent store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using `createOrRecoverPersistedTo` instead of `createPersistedTo` method. Because of this, my other process was not seeing the entire data.

As described in [Recovery](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map#recovery) section in the tutorial elaborates:

> .recoverPersistedTo() needs to access the Chronicle Map exclusively. If a concurrent process is accessing the Chronicle Map while another process is attempting to perform recovery, result of operations on the accessing process side, and results of recovery are unspecified. The data could be corrupted further. You must ensure no other process is accessing the Chronicle Map store when calling for .recoverPersistedTo() on this store."

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty strange. Size in Chronicle Map is not stored in a single memory location. `ChronicleMap.size()` walks through and sums each segment's size. So size is "weakly consistent" and if one process constantly writes to a Map, `size()` calls from multiple threads/processes could return slightly different values. But if nobody writes to a map (e. g. in your case just after loading, when process A hasn't yet started writing) all callers should see the same value.

Instead of `getAll()` and analyzing output manually, you can try to "count" entries by something like

```
int entries = 0;
for (K k : map.keySet()) {
    entries++;
}
```

Comment: Today, I tried to apply your suggested way and it is not showing me the correct results. The lost is almost 50%. Is there a way to diagnose the issue? I am able to reproduce this consistently on my system(Windows environment). Unfortunately, I won't be able to post the code.

Comment: Do you use `createPersistedTo()` or `createOrRecoverPersistedTo()` method in the Process B to open the map? Could you also try to run your case in Linux environment?

Comment: I am using `createOrRecoverPersistedTo()`

Comment: After changing to `createPersistedTo()`, I see the same counts on both the sides. Is there a reason why do I see different behaviour? I have read the Javadoc cursorily of `createOrRecoverPersistedTo` but didn't read about any of such a side effect.

Comment: In the Javadoc, it is explicitly stated that this method delegates to `recoverPersistedTo()`. The documentation to that metjod, in turn, states "At the moment this method is called and executed, no other thread or process should be mapping to the given file, and trying to access the given file."

Comment: [Recovery](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map#recovery) section in the tutorial elaborates: ".recoverPersistedTo() needs to access the Chronicle Map exclusively. If a concurrent process is accessing the Chronicle Map while another process is attempting to perform recovery, result of operations on the accessing process side, and results of recovery are unspecified. The data could be corrupted further. You must ensure no other process is accessing the Chronicle Map store when calling for .recoverPersistedTo() on this store."

Comment: Could you please update the post, or write a self-answer and accept it, so that other readers could quickly see the reason and solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118444/discussion-between-vijar-and-leventov).